# Android translation animation to move item from top left to bottom right?

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<translate 
    android:duration="1000" 
    android:repeatCount="0" 
    android:fromXDelta="0%p" 
    android:toXDelta="80%p" 
    android:fromYDelta="0.0" 
    android:toYDelta="80%p" />
</set>
```

Currently using this to try and move from top left to bottom right, it works such that it does move in the correct direction but pays no attention to the bounds of the activity/textview(which is being animated) it simply goes off the screen! How can i define the translation to stay within bounds?

Comment: What happens when you use 5%p instead of 80%p?? It could be moving 80% of the parent width. But the anchor point is top left corner. So anchor point could be in screen. But the entire picture may not be.

Comment: It just goes less far? aha